# Jquery equivalent of HTML placeholder

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, submit, placeholder

When making a jquery placeholder equivalent i ran into the problem of the form submission. Right now the value changes on focus/focusout but the problem i run into is the fields cant be left blank but the form validation reads the default as a value so it allows it. I tried doing a check for submit() and onclick(). Onclick for the submit button and submit for the form itself. Neither worked. I need to check when it is submitted if the values are the default values or not. And if they are, hopefully make it so it makes the value blank before submission. That way drupals built in error system will trigger rather then building my own.

Current code for placeholder text.

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    // for name field
    $('#edit-submitted-name').focus(function(){
        if ( $('#edit-submitted-name').val() == 'Name...' ) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).css('color', '#000');
        }
    });
    $('#edit-submitted-name').focusout(function(){
        if ( !$('#edit-submitted-name').val() ) {
            $(this).val('Name...');
            $(this).css('color', '#abadb3');
        }
    });
    //for email address field
    $('#edit-submitted-email-address').focus(function(){
        if ( $('#edit-submitted-email-address').val() == 'Email Address...' ) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).css('color', '#000');
        }
    });
    $('#edit-submitted-email-address').focusout(function(){
        if ( !$('#edit-submitted-email-address').val() ) {
            $(this).val('Email Address...');
            $(this).css('color', '#abadb3');
        }
    });
    // for email field
    $('#edit-submitted-email').focus(function(){
        if ( $('#edit-submitted-email').val() == 'Email...' ) {
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).css('color', '#000');
        }
    });
    $('#edit-submitted-email').focusout(function(){
        if ( !$('#edit-submitted-email').val() ) {
            $(this).val('Email...');
            $(this).css('color', '#abadb3');
        }
    });

    $('#edit-submitted-name').val('Name...');
    $('#edit-submitted-name').css('color', '#abadb3');
    $('#edit-submitted-email-address').val('Email Address...');
    $('#edit-submitted-email-address').css('color', '#abadb3');
    $('#edit-submitted-email').val('Email...');
    $('#edit-submitted-email').css('color', '#abadb3');

}
```

Comment: It may be a good idea to make this code more generic.  You've built specific solutions for specific fields.  That's good... but what if you still used the HTML5 placeholder attribute to define "Email" and then with jQuery did something like... $('input[placeholder]').focus(...); to swap out the text when you focused any field that contained a placeholder attribute.  It would significantly reduce the amount of code you have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works great for me.

```
$('form.webform-client-form input#edit-submit').click(function(){
        if ($('#edit-submitted-name').val() == 'Name...') {
            $('#edit-submitted-name').val('');
            $('form.webform-client-form').submit();
        }
        if ($('#edit-submitted-email-address').val() == 'Email Address...') {
            $('#edit-submitted-email-address').val('');
            $('form.webform-client-form').submit();
        }
        if ($('#edit-submitted-email').val() == 'Email...') {
            $('#edit-submitted-email').val('');
            $('form.webform-client-form').submit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: `$('form.webform-client-form input#edit-submit')` only needs to be `$('#edit-submit')` unless you have 2 buttons on the page with the same ID.

Comment: Even if you did try to use the same ID twice, only the first would be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery placeholder plugin :  [jquery.placeholder.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Watermark is good example for placeholder :-

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a plugin for something like this.  That seems like it's probably overkill.

Are you saying you've done something like....

```
$('#formId').submit(function () {
    //check all inputs in the form, if their values match the placeholders then remove the values

    //returning true or false here will either continue form submission or stop it (i think)
});
```

When you inspect the element, do you see any event listeners on the  tag?  Google Chrome's inspector has a section below CSS on an element which will show you event listeners.  This will help you validate if anything is added as an  `onSubmit`

Comment: The problem with doing it like that is I would have to use my own error system. I will try it though